# Audit Alfresco Share previews

Tags: alfresco, preview, alfresco-share, audit

[Obsolete Alfresco documentation](https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-6056-content-auditing) says:

> the download or preview of content are recorded as a single read

However, with Alfresco 5+ **preview** does not generate any audit event (I just tried).

**QUESTION**: How to make Alfresco log an audit event when someone **previews** a document on Alfresco Share? I am not too worried about thumbnails, but at least for the "Document Details" page:

[image: Alfresco Share Document Details preview]

Here is my audit application configuration:

```
audit.alfresco-access.enabled=true
audit.tagging.enabled=false
audit.filter.alfresco-access.default.enabled=true
audit.filter.alfresco-access.transaction.type=cm:folder;cm:content
audit.filter.alfresco-access.transaction.action=CREATE|READ|UPDATE CONTENT|CHECK IN|DELETE|COPY|MOVE
audit.audit-custom.enabled=true
audit.audit-custom.sub-actions.enabled=false
```

Comment: To be sûre, you're interested in the Alfresco audit mecanism, not the share activity notification mecanism : https://community.alfresco.com/community/ecm/blog/2014/10/02/alfresco-community-50b#activities ?

Comment: I wanted to use Audit, but if preview is not visible in Audit, then I guess I will have to investigate the technology described in your link, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Your filter for actions is not set right,
Please note that you should be using `;` for separating multiple possible values, not `|`.
So, I think you should be able to get previews and downloads audited with:

```
audit.filter.alfresco-access.transaction.action=CREATE;READ;UPDATE CONTENT;CHECK IN;DELETE;COPY;MOVE
```

Please note also that you might want to audit one extra action : `READCONTENT`